# Music mood classification

Tags: signal-processing, classification, supervised-learning

I am working on classifying the songs into different moods like happy, sad, passionate, aggressive etc. I want to separate different parts of songs and have a mood label for each part using Supervised Machine Learning.

Are there any available datasets of music with mood labels already annotated  which can be used for my purpose? Besides, are there any known methods to deal with same other than extracting features such as rhythm, mode, pitch, timbre ?

Comment: I don't know about the datasets, but I guess you could also try and use the lyrics (if any) using some NLP techniques (e.g. sentiment analysis).

Comment: Wont that fail if I want same algorithm to perform well for all sort of songs in different languages? Besides, I am interested in dealing only with the music in songs..